Variance of product of multiple i.i.d. random variables?
Definition: Random variables X1, X2, ..., Xn are said to be independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) if they are independent, and they have the same marginal distributions:
FX1(x)=FX2(x)=...=FXn(x), for all x∈R.
The Expected Value of their product will be:
E[X1*X2*⋯*Xn] = E[X1]*E[X2]*⋯*E[Xn] = E[X1]*E[X1]*⋯*E[X1] = (E[X1])^n
Question: What will be their Variance?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

For $n=2$ this is a special case of the duplicate.  For $n\gt 2,$ apply the result iteratively.
